# Dice Histogram - OOP (Homework)

Tags: python

I'm a beginner in Python and I've been trying to unsuccessfully solve an exercise for the past days. It's an Object Oriented Programming exercise that the teacher gave us to do.

Here's the main exercise and code provided:

---

## Exercise:

In this assignment, you will write a program to build a histogram of dice rolls.  The user is asked how many rounds (of rolling two dice) to do.  The program should simulate that many random rounds, and outputs a histogram counting the number of times the total of the two dice was 2, 3, 4 ... up to 12.  Here is a typical run:

How many rounds do you want to do? (or Enter to exit): 1000000

After 1000000 rounds:
2 : count is 28012 or 2 %

3 : count is 55665 or 5 %

4 : count is 83513 or 8 %

5 : count is 110874 or 11 %

6 : count is 138351 or 13 %

7 : count is 166296 or 16 %

8 : count is 139313 or 13 %

9 : count is 110814 or 11 %

10 : count is 83521 or 8 %

11 : count is 55792 or 5 %

12 : count is 27849 or 2 %

The idea is to have a three layered approach:

1)  Main code creates a "Game" object.  The main code then runs in a loop, asking the user how many rounds to do, then tells the Game object to "run" the simulation.

2)  The Game object's initialization should create 13 "Bin" objects - one to represent each possible total (even though it is impossible to get a zero or a one with two dice.) and stores these objects in list of Bin objects.  Then when the main code tells the Game object to run, the Game object should reset the Bin objects and do the given number of simulated rolls.  With each roll, it should tell the appropriate bin to increment itself.  At the end, it should print a header, then tell each Bin object to show it's report.

3)  Each Bin object should be initialized with it's bin number and maintain a count of how many times the roll totaled the amount represented by the Bin.  The Bin object should have the following methods:

`__init__`   - will be passed in the bin identifier (a number between zero and 12)

`reset`    - will be passed in the total number of rolls to be done

`increment`   - no values to be passed in

`show` - no values to be passed in.  Called when the simulation is over.  It should only print if the bin identifier is 2 or more.  It should calculate the percentage and print the bin identifier, the count, and the percent.

So, the initial file provided by the teacher is:

### Initial Code (Blank):

```
import random

class Bin():
    def __init__(self, binIdentifier):
        pass

    def reset(self, nRoundsToDo):
        pass

    def increment(self):
        pass

    def show(self):
        pass


class GameMgr():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def run(self, nRounds):
        pass

oGameMgr = GameMgr()
while True:
    maxRounds = input('How many rounds do you want to do? (or Enter to exit): ')
    if maxRounds == '':
        break
    maxRounds = int(maxRounds)
    oGameMgr.run(maxRounds)

print('OK bye')
```

Here's what I've accomplished so far:

```
# Dice - count totals in user-defined number of rounds

import random

class Bin():

    def __init__(self, binIdentifier):
        self.binIdentifier = binIdentifier
        binIdentifier = 0
        self.number_of_rounds = 0

    def reset(self, nRoundsToDo):
        self.nRoundsToDo = nRoundsToDo
        nRoundsToDo = 0
        self.bin_count = 0

    def increment(self):
        self.bin_count = self.bin_count + 1

    def show(self):
        print(bin_count)
        self.bin_chances = self.bin_count/self.number_of_rounds
        print(bin_chances)


class GameMgr():

    def __init__(self):
        self.bins_list = [ ]
        for i in range(0,13):
            self.bins_list.append(Bin(i))

    def run(self, nRounds):
        self.nRounds = nRounds
        dice1 = random.randint(1,6)
        dice2 = random.randint(1,6)

        for i in self.bins_list:
            i.reset(self.nRoundsToDo)

        for o in self.bins_list:
            bin_roll = dice1 + dice2
            self.bins_list[bin_roll].increment()

oGameMgr = GameMgr()

while True:
    maxRounds = input('How many rounds do you want to do? (or Enter to exit): ')
    if maxRounds == '':
        break
    maxRounds = int(maxRounds)
    oGameMgr.run(maxRounds)

print('OK bye')
```

Comment: Please also add what is or is not working. Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing camelCase and snake_case for variable names (your class names are fine). Pick one naming convention and stick with it.

In your `Bin`'s `__init__` method, you have:

```
class Bin():

    def __init__(self, binIdentifier):
        self.binIdentifier = binIdentifier
        binIdentifier = 0
        self.number_of_rounds = 0
```

Setting binIdentifier to zero is not required, as this does basically nothing.

In your `Bin`'s `reset` method, you have:

```
    def reset(self, nRoundsToDo):
        self.nRoundsToDo = nRoundsToDo
        nRoundsToDo = 0
        self.bin_count = 0
```

Again, you do not need the set the parameter (nRoundsToDo) to zero. According to this method, your class has an instance variable named `nRoundsToDo`, but according to your `__init__` method your class also has an instance variable by the name of `number_of_rounds`. It seems to me that both of these are supposed to represent the same quantity. Pick one and stick with it (I personally like `number_of_rounds` better). <s>In addition, and perhaps more critically, a Bin object shouldn't really care about how many rounds there are. It's the GameMgr (Game Manager) class that cares about the number of rounds. I would give the GameMgr class this instance variable.</s>
Edit* It seems that the Bin class really does need to know about the number of rounds (in the show method, to calculate the percentage).

Also, you'll want your `Bin`'s `__init__` to set the `bin_count` to zero initially.

Finally, your `GameMgr`'s `run` method needs to use the number of rounds in some way. You'll have to create a loop that rolls two dice n number of times (where n is the number of rounds).